# DynamicProperty Breaks PropertyWrapper Outside SwiftUI.View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, property-wrapper

Consider the following property wrapper. It keeps track of value in `wrappedValue`, and also caches old value in `wrappedValueOld`.

```swift
@propertyWrapper struct OldValueCache<Value>: DynamicProperty {
    @State private var field: Value
    var wrappedValue: Value {
        get {
            field
        }
        nonmutating set {
            wrappedValueOld = field
            field = newValue
        }
    }

    @State private(set) var wrappedValueOld: Value?

    init(wrappedValue: Value) {
        self._field = .init(initialValue: wrappedValue)
    }
}
```

To test it, consider the following `View`:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @OldValueCache var a: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(content: {
            Text("\(a) \(_a.wrappedValueOld.map { .init($0) } ?? "nil")")
            
            Button("Increment", action: { a += 1 })
        })
            .onAppear(perform: foo)
    }
    
    private func foo() {
        @OldValueCache var b: Int = 0
        print(b, _b.wrappedValueOld.map { .init($0) } ?? "nil")
        
        b += 1
        print(b, _b.wrappedValueOld.map { .init($0) } ?? "nil")
    }
}
```

It contains a `Text` that displays current and old value, and a `Button` that increments that value. By tapping on the button, we can see a proper behavior. `Text` shows "0 nil", then "1 0", "2 1", "3 2", etc.

However, variable with that property wrapper breaks in a method. `foo` is called on `onAppear(perform:)` which should print "0 nil" and then "1 0". But, "0 nil" is printed each time. `DynamicProperty` `protocol` seems to cause this.

Alternately, we can remove conformance and end up with:

```swift
@propertyWrapper struct OldValueCache<Value> {
    private var field: Value
    var wrappedValue: Value {
        get {
            field
        }
        set {
            wrappedValueOld = field
            field = newValue
        }
    }

    private(set) var wrappedValueOld: Value?

    init(wrappedValue: Value) {
        self.field = wrappedValue
    }
}
```

This time, `foo` method works properly, but since `OldValueCache` is no longer dynamic, `body` breaks, and `Button` needs to be commented out.

Is this expected behavior? What are the possible solutions to make a property wrapper work in both cases, without duplicating the declaration?